# ${'varname_'.$x} variable in PHP

Tags: php, variables

Can someone please remind me how you call this type of variable

`${'varname_'.$x}`

Thanks!

Comment: [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)!

Comment: Ah true! thanks. Maybe you want to add this as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: please consult the PHP Manual before asking questions.

Comment: @Gordon: It's a little hard to search for something when you don't know what it's called.

Comment: @Rocket No, it isnt. OP knew it's variables, so heading to the chapter about variables would have easily answered the question. Please dont defend laziness and lacking research.

Comment: @Gordon Even I can't argue with that, however there are times when you need to get to an answer asap. I can only confirm that I haven't researched enough before posting the question (I researched along), buy only cause I needed a fast answer! I refuse accept the 'lazy' tag :-)

Comment: very difficult to search..........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)!

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$varname = 'varname_'.$x;
echo $$varname;
```

Comment: I actually meant how you name it (variable variable) :) vote up though, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

variable varibales!!!

```
$var = "varname$x";
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++)
{
    echo $$var;
}
```

edit ====

SHOULD BE:

```
for($x=0;$x<10;$x++)
{
    $var = "varname$x";
    echo $$var;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't actually work.  `$var` is evaluated when it's declared, and since `$x` isn't declared yet, `$var` will just be `'varname'`, it won't change.

Comment: correct!!!! u spotted my 'deliberate' mistake. var declaration should of course be inside the loop...

Answer (score 1):

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).  Your example could be used like so:

```
$varname_0 = 'Hello World!';
$x = 0;
echo ${'varname_'.$x}; // 'Hello World!'
```